# Job is not returning error when SSIS package have an error

Tags: sql, ssis, package, jobs

I have a job that is running a SSIS package but even when the package have an error I am always getting sucess on the job. The image below it is possible to see the package error on Integration Service Catalog Report.

[image]

However, in the "all runs" area, processing is successful.

[image]

The job was set up normally:

[image]

I don't understand what's wrong with the process.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance for all your help.

Comment: It seems that you have a task or something, inside your package that fails. But that task failing doesn't mean that the package as a whole as failed.
You probably need to change your SSIS package to exist on failure. 
But would need more info regarding SSIS package to know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I remember that I had a similar issue in the past and I solve with a "patch" variable, in the node that I had problems, I initialized this variable with a false value and if the process was completed then I changed to true and the last step of the SSIS was to evaluate the variable and in case to be false, then I sent an alert email considering that the process had failed.

But, as Mr.Jones has mentioned, maybe community needs more info about your workflow to know better how to help in a more professional way.